# Swing GUI design with JScrollPane and JLayeredPane

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I would like to have a GUI setup like the diagram below.

[image]

The `JLayeredPane` should always be the same size, but the `JPanel` and the `JScrollPane` can change in size. I need the `JScrollPane` to be able to display the `JLayedPane` by clicking the arrows and what not if the `JPanel` and `JScrollPane` are not large enough to show the entire `JLayeredPane`.

The problem is that with the code below, the `JLayeredPane` always expands to fit the size of the `JScrollPane` and in the event that the `JScrollPane` is smaller than the `JLayeredPane`, it does not provide the scrolling ability.

Any Ideas on what is going on? Is there simpler code to achieve this?

Thanks

```
contentPanePanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
contentPaneScollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
contentPane = new javax.swing.JLayeredPane();

contentPanePanel.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0), 1, true));

contentPane.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
contentPane.setVerifyInputWhenFocusTarget(false);

contentPaneScollPane.setViewportView(contentPane);

javax.swing.GroupLayout contentPanePanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(contentPanePanel);

contentPanePanel.setLayout(contentPanePanelLayout);

contentPanePanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
    contentPanePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addComponent(contentPaneScollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 968, Short.MAX_VALUE)
);
contentPanePanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
    contentPanePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addComponent(contentPaneScollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 628, Short.MAX_VALUE)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the trick is to add the layered pane to a panel that uses a layout manager which will keep the layered pane centered. Something like:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class ScrollPaneSSCCE
{
    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JPanel center = new JPanel();
        center.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(300, 300) );
        center.setBackground( Color.RED );

        JPanel main = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout() );
        main.add(center, new GridBagConstraints());

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Basic ScrollPaneSSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new JScrollPane( main ) );
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: GridBagLayout worked perfect for keeping it centered. Thanks!

Comment: Is it correct, that the `JPanel center` in this example is meant to be the `JLayeredPane contentPane` that is mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 1):

This is the intended behavior of a `JScrollPane`.. it provides a viewport to the underlying component. This means that, if the component is a `JLayeredPane`, then the whole pane is considered as the attached view of the scrollpane and there are no invisible insets that place the layered pane centered as you want while keeping the scrollpane bigger.

To solve your problem you could add the `JLayeredPane`to a `JPanel`and then add this `JPanel`as the view of the `JScrollPane`, after having set the correct insets of the layered pane so that it stays in middle as you want.